# Как просмотреть сообщение в канале/группе телеграмма Telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

У меня есть код, который чекает все сообщения группы/канала телеграмма, я долго искал инфу в гугле, но ничего не нашёл, мне надо чтобы на сообщении отмечалось, что аккаунт просмотрел сообщение

Мой код парсинга сообщений:

```
async def look(account: dict, chat: str, delay_before_start: int):
    look_running = True
    client: TelegramClient = account["client"]
    phone = account["phone"]
    while look_running:
        try:
            async for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
                if message.id == 1:
                    await sleep(20)
                    stop_loop()
                print(message.id)
                await sleep(5)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(f"ошибка аккаунта: {e}")
            await sleep(2)
        await sleep(group_delay + 2)
```

Даже когда отправляешь в сообщение в группу/канал или комментишь или ставишь реакцию на сообщение, всё равно оно не просматривается, помогите, пожалуйста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(на картинке комментраии это и есть аккаунты, коммент на пост есть, а показано что непрочитано)